# Getting Type Error Trying to create a month-year column from date ranges in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to follow the solution provided [Find all months between two date columns and generate row for each month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276737/find-all-months-between-two-date-columns-and-generate-row-for-each-month) and I'm hitting a wall as I'm getting an error. What I want to do is create a Year-Month column for each year-month that exists in the startdate and enddate range for each row. When I tried to follow the above linked Stack, I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot convert input ... Name: ServiceStartDate, dtype: datetime64[ns]] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp

I have no idea how to fix this. Please help!

**Sample Data**

|  | ID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 311566 | 2021-10-01 | 2024-09-30 |
| 2 | 235216 | 2020-11-01 | 2020-11-30 |
| 3 | 157054 | 2021-10-01 | 2023-09-30 |
| 4 | 159954 | 2021-01-01 | 2023-12-31 |
| 5 | 255815 | 2019-11-01 | 2022-10-31 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem (sorry for the long response delay). The problem was that my data had a time stamp associated with it. I needed to change the date field to y/m/-01 format using the following code.

```
df['date] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-01'))
```

Then I used the solution below to get all the months/years that exist between the min and max dates as a single column.

```
df.merge(df.apply(lambda s: pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), 
                            df['date'].max(), freq='MS'), 1).explode("").rename('Month'),
                            left_index=True, right_index=True)
```